# Windows 7 is not recognizing the UDF filesystem of a CD

Tags: windows-7, compact-disc, udf

I have a UDF CD that I recently received, but I cannot use it.

The disc reads fine, but when I open it, I see a single `README.txt`, that tells me the disk is UDF-formatted, and I need a computer that can read the UDF format (the readme is on a secondary CDFS filesystem, it seems).

Windows 7 has UDF drivers (and I have installed a hotfix for UDF-related issues), but it is not detecting the UDF filesystem.

Is there any way to get Windows 7 to read and mount this UDF filesystem?

Comment: i found microsoft link regarding your error http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itpromedia/thread/0dc7b8ad-3d9e-4e12-8aca-28c065c8897b/  hope it may solve the problem please mention your problem with little detail like udf message error number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open Disk Management (Start > Run > `diskmgmt.msc`). Check to see what volumes are present on the CD in the drive. If you can see the UDF volume and the CDFS one, then Windows is just mounting the wrong one. You may have to manually mount one of them (Right click > Change Drive Letter and Paths... > Add... > OK > OK) to see the "correct" one.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know how to make Windows mount the correct one by default. You may want to ask that as a separate question if you consider that functionality important.

Comment: @K.A for me windows 7 cannot recognize the CD yet. What can i do in this case. Details here http://superuser.com/questions/1099563/i-cant-read-cd-disc-from-sony-camcorder-in-windows-7. thanks