# I can't read CD DISC from Sony Camcorder in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, dvd, formatting, compact-disc, camera

I have a Sony camcorder (digital video camera) [DCR-DVD106E](http://www.sony.ee/support/en/product/DCR-DVD106E). The camcorder works with mini CD's from Sony (I found the CD's in the package I have bought so it seems they are original).

To read the CD I can use the interface from the camcorder to connect it with PC using a cable but I didn't do that (the cable was missing).

After inserting the CD into my laptop CD PLAYER for the first time the laptop finds some difficulties opening the Disc and I was not able to read the content.

After many tries, it tell me that there is some problems that windows needs to fix so I clicked OK (wish I think was a big mistake) and after this process I couldn't read the content.

After this, the camera doesn't recognize the CD with the error : **Disc error unsupported format**, and after finding the cable I couldn't read the CD drive using the camcorder as I have used to do. But when inserting the CD into my CD player it tell me **you need to format the disk before you can use it** (right that seems to be a good advice after windows has corrupted my data).

Using Nero I found that the drive is Sony ddx c2000-A-o, if this info can help !

Please it's critical and i don't want to loose all my personal recorded videos.
NB: I'm using Windows 7 64-bits and the CD is DVD-RW.

Update: I have tried to recover data at least using several softwares:

> 1. CD Recovery Toolbox Free  (Unabe to read CD)
> 2. Roadkil's unstoppable copier (Unabe to copy CD)
> 3. CDCheck (Give me the device is not ready)
> 4. EaseUS Data Recovery Wizard (CD not found)
> 5. ... (your suggestions)

Thanks a lot in advance. Any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Have you proceeded with formatting your CD as Windows suggested? Is there any critical data you want to keep? Do you have more of these CD's? [Sony official website](http://pdf.crse.com/manuals/2319497111.pdf)  says that there is a memory card inside your camera, have you tried to use it?

Comment: Of course i want to keep my data on the CD so formatting it's not a solution. I have a memory card wish contains photos only. Videos are recorded in the CD. thanks

Comment: If you insert this CD containing videos into camera will you be able to access CD content?
If the content is accessible then you will be able to connect your camera to computer via a wire with a CD in it and see if you can access your videos.

Comment: yes but after using windows error checking and repair automatically i couldn't even read the CD in the camcorder and it tell me Disc error unsupported format. I am connecting the camcorder with a USB cable and the CD displays but cannot be accessed i have runned also chkdsk but it tell me disk is write protected