# Open a CD that contains file .zl

Tags: windows-10, 7-zip, compact-disc

I have a CD that was created in 2003. This CD used to contains some pictures in folders. Now I need some of those pictures but I am not able to recover them. The reason is that once I insert the CD in the computer (Windows 7) some weird files appear into the CD instead of the photos:

1. `Autorun.inf`
2. `UdfrChk` that sounds like an executable
3. `udfrinst.zl` that in my opinion is it something like an archive, and I may be able to recover the pictures from there

I have tried several methods to decompress the `.zl` file (`gzip`,`7zip`,`minizip`,..) but none of them worked. It would be helpful to recover the files. I think that it is also important to mention that once my boyfriend tried to launch the executable, his computer asks for installing `Roxio UDf` reader and all the anti-viruses he had installed try to stop this. Thank you fon any help.

Comment: What size is the file? Is there any print on the CD that would identify the maker (like a film company or whatever)?

Comment: From looking on the Internet it appears you have a hybrid CD that has both a normal ISO9660 section and a UDF section. The normal section will be readable by any computer while the UDF section may, on older computers, need drivers which are in the normal section but probably won't work on your current OS. The solution at https://superuser.com/questions/460582/windows-7-is-not-recognizing-the-udf-filesystem-of-a-cd might work.

Comment: @DanielB: It sounds like it was written locally using Roxio DirectCD (which provided drag&drop incremental writing in Win98/XP era, and used the UDF format)... The odd thing is, Windows 7 already has built-in support for reading UDF discs and should have recognized the disk (this installer should only be necessary on Windows XP and older systems).

Comment: Windows probably still has problems with multi-session discs. I also found [this](https://www.roxio.com/en/support/software-updates/udf/), which may or may not work.

Comment: If you are able to make an image of the whole CD and the files are not too sensitive, you can try sharing it with us and we can try to have a look

Comment: @DanielB the CD contains some pictures of the electrical system of my house. It is a CD that has been made by the electricians that made my home lots of years ago, it is a simple CD of pictures

Comment: Thank you, I will try all your solutions